# Do catch block executes if logger.error() hit/show in try block

Tags: java, try-catch

Maybe a basic question, But I want to know, like if I have `logger.error()` in the try block. Does it call the catch block that is written after the try block, if the try block executes.

E.g:

```
       try {
            
                logger.error(String.format("No data found for pId: %s " +
                        "Id : %s for xyzId : %s", placeId, pId, xyzId));
                System.out.println("Executed_1")
           
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            logger.error("Error occured while reading prices section from revision") 
        }
       System.out.println("Executed_2")
```

Comment: When you said "if the condition is true in try block" you meant `if (true) {`? Then the condition will always be true :-)

Answer (score 0):

The catch block will only be executed if a RuntimeException is thrown within the try block. If logger.error() doesn't throw that exception, then calling it will not trigger your catch block.

Comment: So here(above code) try block content does't  throw runtime exception here ? right